# SSL Exception with MySQL when upgrading to Java JDK 11

Tags: java, mysql, ssl, jdbc

I was trying to update my project SDK from JDK 10 to 11. However, when my program tries to connect to my MySQL server (currently hosted on my local machine) I get a javax.net.ssl.SSLException.

I see there are some changes to SSL in JDK 11 but I don't know what they mean or how to fix my program:

> security-libs/javax.net.ssl ➜ Disabled all DES TLS Cipher Suites 
>   DES-based TLS cipher suites are considered obsolete and should no
>   longer be used. DES-based cipher suites have been deactivated by
>   default in the SunJSSE implementation by adding the "DES" identifier
>   to the jdk.tls.disabledAlgorithms security property. These cipher
>   suites can be reactivated by removing "DES" from the
>   jdk.tls.disabledAlgorithms security property in the java.security file
>   or by dynamically calling the Security.setProperty() method. In both
>   cases re-enabling DES must be followed by adding DES-based cipher
>   suites to the enabled cipher suite list using the
>   SSLSocket.setEnabledCipherSuites() or
>   SSLEngine.setEnabledCipherSuites() methods.
>
> Note that prior to this change, DES40_CBC (but not all DES) suites
>   were disabled via the jdk.tls.disabledAlgorithms security property.

EDIT:

Ok, I figured out a solution. I wasn't aware that I could add useSSL=false to my database url. I did that and everything works fine!

Comment: Please provide your solution as a solution, not an edit of your question, then validate your own answer so that the question gets closed.

Comment: "I wasn't aware that I could add `useSSL=false` to my database url. I did that and everything works fine!" is not really a solution in your case! You effectively removed a security aspect when communicating with your database. In you situation, I'd consider searching for a real solution of this problem.

Comment: @MWiesner As far as I understand, while everything is on my local machine (MySQL server and my program that accesses it), then SSL is not important.

However, I do plan on putting the MySQL server and program on a remote server, and may need to access the MySQL server remotely. In that case, it's my understanding that SSL would be important to protect my log-in credentials (MySQL password).

I'm just learning how all of this works so please correct me if I am wrong. Thanks!

Comment: Please post the full exception stacktrace

Answer (score 0):

In my case I was never using SSL (as I was connecting to a MySQL server on my local machine). In JDK 10 this worked fine, but in JDK 11 I needed to add useSSL=false to my database url which solved the problem.